For positive $a,b,c$ with $abc=1$, how to prove $2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3\ge 3(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)$?
This is a question derived from another exercise problem for high school math contests. I hope this new question is also interesting.

If $a>0$, $b>0$, and $c>0$ with $abc=1$, prove that $$2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3\ge 3(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2).$$

However, I only managed to use weighted AM-GM inequality
$$ 
\frac{\frac{2}{3}a^3 + \frac{4}{3}b^3 + abc }{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3}+1} \ge 
a^{3/3}b^{5/3}c^{1/3}=
\left(ab^2\right)^{2/3}
$$ and its cyclic permutations $a\rightarrow b$, $b\rightarrow c$ and $c\rightarrow a$
to obtain
$$
2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3\ge 3\left[ \left(ab^2\right)^{2/3}+ \left(bc^2\right)^{2/3}+\left(ca^2\right)^{2/3} \right].
$$
But I do not know how to prove the question without the extra exponent $2/3$. Any hints are appreciated.

Hint: Use Schur's inequality to deal with $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3abc$. The rest should be obvious. $\quad$ (After we replace 3 with $3abc$, we can drop the condition that $abc=1$) AM-GM alone is doomed to failure, because of the $abc$ term leading to $a^x b^y c^z$, which doesn't exist on the RHS (IE You complain about exponents being different)

@CalvinLin Thanks a lot for the nice solution and the explanation!

Can you write it up as a solution?

@CalvinLin Yes, will try.

The following is based on the hint from Calvin Lin's comment.
Replace the $3$ on the LHS by $3abc$ and apply the following special case of Schur's inequality
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3 +3abc \ge (ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)+(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a).\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Then it remains to show
$$ (a^3+b^3+c^3) + (a^2b+b^2c+c^2a) \ge 2(ab^2 +bc^2 +ca^2) \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
in order to get the wanted inequality by adding $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$.
But
$$\begin{align}
 b^3 + a^2b &\ge 2\sqrt{a^2b^4}=2ab^2,\\
 c^3 + b^2c &\ge 2\sqrt{b^2c^4}=2bc^2,\\
 a^3 + c^2a &\ge 2\sqrt{c^2a^4}=2ca^2.\\
\end{align}
$$
Adding the above three gives inequality $\eqref{2}$.
